# merging unequal dataframes on multiple columns left_on & right_on

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'email': ['sara@example.com', 'john@example.com', 'Christine@example.com']})
```

df1:

```
    name          email
0   Sara         sara@example.com
1   John         john@example.com
2   Christine    Christine@example.com
```

and the following df2 for more email info for the customers:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'email_id':['sara@example.com',  np.nan , 'flower@example8.com'],

                   'alternate email': ['sara@example.com', 'john.walker@example.com' , 'Christine33@example.com'],
                   'alternate email2': ['sara13@example.com', 'john@example.com', 'Christine@example.com']})
```

df2:

```
    email_id                alternate email             alternate email2
0   sara@example.com        sara@example.com            sara13@example.com
1   NaN                     john.walker@example.com         john@example.com
2   flower@example8.com     Christine33@example.com     Christine@example.com
```

now I want to merge both dataframes on the left (df1) and doing the matching on multiple columns on df2

If I merge using the `left_on` and `right_on`:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='email', right_on='email_id', how='left')
```

Then only one customer will be matched:

```
    name                  email               email_id          alternate email     alternate email2
0   Sara               sara@example.com       sara@example.com  sara@example.com    sara13@example.com
1   John               john@example.com             NaN                    NaN                NaN
2   Christine         Christine@example.com         NaN                    NaN                NaN
```

I do not know if there is a method to merge one column on the left and multiple columns on the right df. I can do multiple matching one by one but it is not practical!

**Edit:**

Expected output:

```
    name            email                        email_id            alternate email            alternate email2
0   Sara            sara@example.com            sara@example.com     sara@example.com           sara13@example.com
1   John            john@example.com            NaN                  john.walker@example.com    john@example.com
2   Christine       Christine@example.com       flower@example8.com  Christine33@example.com    Christine@example.com
```

it is like using the following code:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='email', right_on=['email_id','alternate email','alternate email2'], how='left')
```

but an error of unequal length of dataframes will appear:

```
len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)
```

Comment: upload sample of the csv file/text rather than dataframe printout. most of the time, such issues can be resolved in the csv itself before going to dataframe. hence, the raw csv is very important......... also, show an example of the expected format you want.

Comment: what is your expected output from the given sample dataframe?

Comment: I added the expected output, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

The idea is to merge df1 on each column of cols(present in df2)

```
cols=['email_id', 'alternate email', 'alternate email2']
out=(pd.concat([df1.merge(df2[x], left_on='email', right_on=x, how='left') for x in cols])
       .dropna(subset=cols,how='all'))
out[cols]=out[cols].fillna(df2[cols])
out=out.drop_duplicates()
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your desired output

Comment: @Mtaly corrected a little typo changed `subset=df2.columns` to `subset=cols` in `dropna()` method....kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
indexes = df2.unstack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True) \
             .rename('email').drop_duplicates().dropna() \
             .reset_index()

df1 = df1.merge(indexes, how='left')
df1 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='index', right_index=True).drop(columns='index')
```

```
>>> df1
        name                  email             email_id          alternate email       alternate email2
0       Sara       sara@example.com     sara@example.com         sara@example.com     sara13@example.com
1       John       john@example.com                  NaN  john.walker@example.com       john@example.com
2  Christine  Christine@example.com  flower@example8.com  Christine33@example.com  Christine@example.com
```